# Woocommerce, where to look to find get_cart() returns?

Tags: woocommerce

I've checked the woocommerce codex but they don't provide the returns of a function like the wordpress codex.

In this case `get_cart()` i know it returns the cart contents but i don't know the keys/values in the array.

Is there a website or method i'm missing?; because i'm wasting my time always looking for the return values of functions in woocommerce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said, it returns an array. The array keys are uniquely generated for each product. The array value is an array of data that includes the product id and product object. Try using something like ’var_dump’ to see exactly what is returned in the array.